# Games installed from repos won't start

Tags: 11.04, gnome, games, official-repositories

I'm running Natty (upgraded from Maverick) with Gnome 3 (from the Gnome 3 PPA, Unity removed), and have recently found that some of my games from the repos no longer work. When I go to start them, I get the message:

```
Failed to launch [app name]. Failed to execute child process [app name] (no such file or directory).
```

I've so far found this on Gweled and PyScrabble. Other games (Mines, Sudoku, Mahjongg), as well as other applications have opened just fine. Gweled used to open fine until recently.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would do is uninstall all the games that don't work anymore:

```
sudo apt-get remove gweled pyscrabble
```

then re-install them:

```
sudo apt-get install gweled pyscrabble
```

Ok so you can run them from terminal but not through launcher. Delete your launchers then Recreate them. sounds like the launcher doesn't have the correct location in launcher or has gotten currupted some how.

Comment: The answer above didn't worked.
I have the same problem here.
The launchers just sopped working few days ago. But I can run they at the terminal.

Comment: Ok so you can run them from terminal but not through launcher. Delete your launchers then Recreate them. sounds like the launcher doesn't have the correct location in launcher or has gotten currupted some how.

Comment: Due to other reasons, I ended up reinstalling my OS. @fevpk, if you could respond with whether freebird's second suggestion works (and if freebird could edit his answer to include the launcher issue), I'll mark this answer as correct.